# Why the ConcurrentLinkedQueue is adding same elements?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, queue, repeat

I'm using the following code to add data into a ConcurrentLinkedQueue. The queue however is adding same chunk over and over. I'm not sure why is it so?

```
byte[] chunk = new byte[20];
        for (int i = 1; i<=data.length; i++){

            if((i-1)%19 != 0){
                chunk[(i-1)%19] = data[i-1];
            }
            else{
                chunk[19] = '?';
                i++;
                myQueue.add(chunk);
            }
        }
```

I checked the values, the chunk is receiving new values every time. Please help.

Comment: you are adding temp into the queue.

Comment: What is the value for temp here?. You are not doing any operations with chuck.

Comment: sorry for the typo...

Comment: can you please tell why with every add to queue, old copy of chunk is being picked and added?

Comment: You're only adding to the queue in the else block, is that what you intend?  Maybe if you can describe in English what the loop is supposed to do it will be more clear what the problem is.